# Django API with multiple calls using try, except

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, api, dictionary

I am trying to make an API endpoint that will take input like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/getslots?car_number=3`and give output as car_number or slot_parking. Here is what I have done:

```
slots = {'ka9865': 1, 'ka9866': 2, 'ka9867': 3}
def get_car(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            car_number = request.GET['car_number']
            for key,value in slots.items():
                if key == car_number:
                    car_slot = value
                    response = json.dumps([{'slot': car_slot}])  
        except (UnboundLocalError):
            slot = request.GET['car_number']
            for key,value in slots.items():
                if value == slot:
                    car_number1 = key     #not entering inside this loop
                    response = json.dumps([{ 'car_number': car_number1}])
        except:
            response = json.dumps([{ 'Error': 'No car with that name/slot'}])                   

    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='text/json')
```

But I am getting error of  `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment`
I am not able to figure out how to do this and also please suggest me if there is any better way of implementing this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to creatwe response already before otherwise the variable will be just in the namespace of the exception block.

```
slots = {'ka9865': 1, 'ka9866': 2, 'ka9867': 3}
def get_car(request):
 response = None # Create default reponse here
 if request.method == 'GET':
    #...
```